# Destroying Requests in Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream, socket.io, request

Recently, I've been trying to wrap my head around infintely long Readable streams using the [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) framework. The way I am implementing this is in a function that gets called several times with the intent of destroying the previous request. Like:

```
var request = require('request');

var start_request = function () {
    curr = request(url).pipe(trumpet)
    curr.destroy();
    curr = request(url + mod).pipe(trumpet);
}
```

But unlike other Readable streams, it does not appear to have a destroy method, and if it call the `start_request` function several times, it just creates several requests. How can I destroy/cancel request?

Comment: What are you trying to do? In this case you should just issue 2 requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.abort()` to destroy a request. Make sure you have an `on('error')` handler as well.

```
var request = require('request');

var start_request = function () {
    curr = request(url);
    curr.on('error', function handleError(err) { /* ... */ });
    curr.pipe(trumpet);

    // Abort request
    curr.abort();

    curr = request(url + mod).pipe(trumpet);
}
```

Comment: I had tried using abort before without success, but the error handler made it work!